# Hwo can I save the registered .nii file in ITK-SNAP

Tags: registration, itk

When I use ITK-SNAP,after rigid registration,I want to save the .nii file.But when I use the button save(in the picture),the .nii file is same as itself before registration.
So I want to know how to save this .nii after registration.[the "save" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eS5Q.png)

So I want to know how to save this .nii after registration.